# Convergence in norm!

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n(x)=\sqrt{n}e^{-nx}$ for $x\in \Omega=(0,1).$
Question: Does $\int_{\Omega}f_n(x)h(x)dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for each $h(x)\in L^1(\Omega)?$.

My intuition is that this is not true, but I cannot find a counterexample or prove if this is the case. 
If it helps, I have already shown that $$||f_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

Also I have shown that $$\int_{\Omega}f_n(x)g(x)dx\rightarrow 0$$ for each $g\in L^2(\Omega).$

$\Large {\bf Edited}$

So I know I claimed above that I have shown that $$\int_{\Omega}f_n(x)g(x)dx\rightarrow 0$$ for each $g\in L^2(\Omega),$ but upon a closer look I am a little confused, and I cannot seem to resolve the confusion.

My original thought was as follows: I could show that the statement is true for every monomial. Then, using a similar logic, I could show that $$\int_{\Omega}f_n(x)P_k(x)dx\rightarrow 0,$$ where $P_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$.

Then, using the fact that every measurable function can be approximated with a continuous function, and the latter with polynomials, I could show that the statement holds in its full generality.

There are two things that are confusing me:

First, why isn't the same logic working in the $L^1$ case? There must be some subtle difference here, but I cannot seem to see it.

Second, each of these functions $f_n\in L^2(\Omega)$ defines a bounded linear functional $F:L^2(\Omega)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $$F_n(g)=\int_{\Omega}f_ng.$$

In Royden (ch. 6, pp 131) they show that $||F_n||=||f_n||_{L^2}.$

But as $n\rightarrow \infty$ this does not approach zero, so wouldn't this imply that there is at least some function $g\in L^2(\Omega)$ for which the statement is wrong??

Thanks for your input!!

Comment: Note that, if $h\in L^1(\Omega)$, then it is bounded, $|h|\leq M$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Hmmm no: $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @julien: Now, you are taking about the Lebesgue integrability in the extended sense. Going back to Lebesgue definition: we see that a function is Lebesgue integrable if it is bounded and measurable.

Comment: Note that, when we say $f\in L^1$, then we really mean Lebesgue definition. Just as we distinguish between Riemann integrability and improper integrals. I hope that's clear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal [$L^p$ space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces).

Comment: @julien: Try to evaluate the example you give in your comment using the original Lebesgue definition and see what you get.

Comment: It is absolutely false that functions in $L^1(\Omega)$ must be bounded.  For instance, if that were true then we would lose the completeness of $L^p$-spaces.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark; I know...I never said they should be bounded :)

Comment: @V-B: I know you didn't.  I was worried that you might be confused by this assertion though.  I'm glad you're not.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: What does $f\in L^{1}$ mean? I am very precise, according to Lebesgue definition the function has to be bounded and measurable.

Comment: @Mhenni: My motivation was to help the OP.  After hearing that s/he has not been led astray by your comments I am no longer interested in the matter.  If *you* have a question abut the space $L^1$, please feel free to ask it on this site.  The definitions here can be found on wikipedia or any introductory text on measure theory, e.g. Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Comment: @Mhenni: Against my better judgment I leave two hints for you to see why what you are saying is wrong.  (i) What are the elements of $L^1(\Omega)$?  They are not even quite functions, but equivalence classes of functions up to measure zero.  Thus it is not even really *meaningful* to say that $f \in L^1(\Omega)$ is bounded: compare that $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is only *essentially* bounded.  (ii) $L^1(\Omega)$ is a Banach space: that's very much the point.  However if we restricted to bounded functions we would not have a Banach space.

Comment: The definition of $\int_{\Omega} f d \mu$ for non-negative measurable functions on p. 19 of Rudin's book.  It is defined for all measurable functions but may be infinite.  On p. 24 of Rudin's book he defines $L^1(\Omega)$ as the set of measurable functions $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int_{\Omega} |f| d\mu < \infty$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal You may not be familiar with the specifics of internet etiquette, but writing in all-caps is generally interpreted as shouting. As a moderator, I want to remind you to treat other users respectfully. As a user who knows some measure theory, I would encourage you to take Pete's suggestions seriously, he is certainly correct in stating that Lebesgue integrable functions may not be bounded.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I did not know this etiquette. Recarding the topic of Lebesgue integrability, I taking about sutle point which is according to Lebesgue definition the function has to be bounded just like for Riemann integrability. However, we can extend Lebesgoe integrability to unbounded functions using some techniques. It is by experience that, we think we have got the right understanding, but we discover that, we have not got it yet. Every real knoledge seeker knows this. Knowledge need patience and time.

Comment: @Mhenni: You asked me for the definition of $L^1(\Omega)$, and I took the time to look up and give you a precise reference to a standard text.  What is your response to that?  Did you look it up in Rudin's text (or some other text, which would say the same thing)?  Do you understand why what you were saying before is wrong?  I am trying to figure out whether you can be reasoned with.  If after more than one day of trying -- including quoting from textbooks -- you cannot be convinced that $L^1$ functions may be unbounded, the answer is clearly **no**.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if anyone could have a look at the "Edited" part of my post!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\in L^1(0,1)$. Then, with the change of variables $y= nx$
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{n}\frac{e^{-nx}}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_0^n \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt{\frac{y}{n}}}dy =\int_0^n \frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt y}dy\rightarrow \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt y}dy\not=0$$

Comment: Because it has a removable singularity and it is Lebesgue integrable in the extended sense.

Comment: Fantastic...I was using $h(x)=\frac{1}{x^a}$ for $a>1$...but they obviously are not in $L^1(\Omega)$...It didn't occur to me to take $a<1.$